# IntelliJ plugin development - loop over only git tracked files

Tags: java, kotlin, intellij-idea, intellij-plugin, ideavim

Currently I am working on an IntelliJ plugin, with this plugin I want to iterate over a list of files that are only tracked by git (so excluding the files in the .gitignores).

I am able to loop over files via [ProjectFileIndex](https://github.com/JetBrains/intellij-community/blob/master/platform/projectModel-api/src/com/intellij/openapi/roots/ProjectFileIndex.java), then I use the [iterateContent](https://github.com/JetBrains/intellij-community/blob/fbbe62e5288a927549a2a2849c718ec3d0a590bc/platform/projectModel-api/src/com/intellij/openapi/roots/FileIndex.java#L57) method with a ContentIterator. This works fine for all project files, however I was wondering if there is a way to do this with only git tracked files. I already looked into the APIs of [git4idea](https://github.com/JetBrains/intellij-community/tree/master/plugins/git4idea/src/git4idea) but I couldn't find any class which provides this functionality. I am completely new to Kotlin and IntelliJ plugin development in general.

Are there any recommendations on how to do this properly?

Comment: You can also ask this question at the official JetBrains forum dedicated to plugin development: https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/topics/200366979-IntelliJ-IDEA-Open-API-and-Plugin-Development

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion @Koyasha , that might indeed be a better place to find someone with this specific Idea plugin development knowledge!

Comment: FYI… If you do find a solution there, you can post and accept an Answer to your own Question here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eventually I used the [isIgnoredFile(file: VirtualFile)](https://github.com/JetBrains/intellij-community/blob/d9d260a048ef2105e801d18ffbca87c108b0a187/platform/vcs-api/src/com/intellij/openapi/vcs/changes/ChangeListManager.java#L263C62-L263C68) function in the `com.intellij.openapi.vcs.changes.ChangeListManager` class in combination with the [ProjectFileIndex](https://github.com/JetBrains/intellij-community/blob/master/platform/projectModel-api/src/com/intellij/openapi/roots/ProjectFileIndex.java) that I was already using.

The ProjectFileIndex instance has a method [iterateContent](https://github.com/JetBrains/intellij-community/blob/d9d260a048ef2105e801d18ffbca87c108b0a187/platform/projectModel-api/src/com/intellij/openapi/roots/FileIndex.java#L45) where you can define your own ContentIterator, within this ContentIteraror you can use the `isIgnoredFile` method from the `ChangeListManager` instance to filter out the VCS ignored files.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).